# Task ':flutter:bundleDebugAar' uses this output of task ':flutter:copyFlutterAssetsDebug' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

I've serious problems building my project on my Windows 10 machine after upgrades of Gradle (8.0), Flutter (3.13.6), Dart (3.1.3) all with Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2 (currently latest one). My project structure is complex. There is a main project, which is a native Android one (Java/Kotlin), it contains a flutter project (project type "module").

The build fails with this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':flutter:bundleDebugAar' (type 'BundleAar').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'D:\x\main-project\flutter-module-project\.android\Flutter\build\intermediates\library_assets\debug\out'.
    
    Reason: Task ':flutter:bundleDebugAar' uses this output of task ':flutter:copyFlutterAssetsDebug' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.
    
    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':flutter:copyFlutterAssetsDebug' as an input of ':flutter:bundleDebugAar'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':flutter:copyFlutterAssetsDebug' from ':flutter:bundleDebugAar' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':flutter:copyFlutterAssetsDebug' from ':flutter:bundleDebugAar' using Task#mustRunAfter.
    
    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.0/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency for more details about this problem.
```

It builds on Macs and one other Windows machine, but not mine. I tried cleaning all (flutter clean, clean project, invalidate caches, manually remove build folders and pubspec.lock) always with the same result.

The suggested solutions aren't working for me, since I don't have a build.gradle file. Just a auto generated one (which shouldn't be modified). Nevertheless I tried modifying, but I'm not even sure what I should add there, since I always get syntax errors.

Any idea what else I can try?

Comment: Solved my issue by changing the way the flutter module is integrated from source code to AAR: https://docs.flutter.dev/add-to-app/android/project-setup?tab=android-archive